# Select the row in same group with minimum value?

Tags: sql, database

```
id  game   point
1    x      5
2    y      4
3    z      6
4    x      2
5    y      5
6    z      8
```

I want to select the record with minimum point in game x,game y, game z

Comment: Add the expected result as well, formatted text here too. And show us your current query attempt. And also tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole record, you will have a little more work to do:

```
SELECT * from table_name
 WHERE (game, point) IN (select game, min(point) from table_name
                       GROUP BY game);
```

Alternatively you could use a CTE, or window functions.

Comment: Great answer as long as OP's dbms support "row and table constructors".

Comment: @RadimBača, yeah, it should have been table_name.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN` aggregate function with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select game, min(point) as minPoint
from your_table_name
group by game;
```

Answer (score 0):

USe aggregate function with group by ,    Try this:

```
select game, MIN(point)
from Table_name
group by game;
```

You can give to name the Aggregate function

```
select game, MIN(point) as Minimum_Points
from Table_name
group by game;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way how to find all values (all attributes) you need even without `GROUP BY` is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.point, t1.[group]
FROM your_table t1
WHERE t1.point = (
      SELECT min(t2.point) 
      FROM your_table t2 
      WHERE t2.[group] = t1.[group]
     )
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use over partition by.

Query:

```
 select id,game,min_point from (
    select id, GAME, POINT,min(POINT) over (PARTITION by GAME) as MIN_POINT
    from YOUR_TABLE) where point = min_point
```

Result:

```
id  game   min_point
1    x     2
2    y     4
3    z     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here, but since we don't know which dbms OP is using,  I'd go with the most general answer:

```
select t1.id, t1.game. t1.point
from tablename t1
join (select game, min(point) as minpoint
      from tablename
      group by game) t2
    on  t1.game = t2.game
    and t1.point = t2.minpoint
```

Have a derived table (i.e. the subquery) with a `GROUP BY` to find each game's min point. `JOIN` with that result.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, this can be done as:-

```
select id,game,point As MinPoint 
from table_name where 
point in (select min(point) from table_name group by game);
```

The output on similar kind of data is as follows:-

Select * from sql_prac;

ID DEPT                        SAL

---

```
     1 A                          2000 
     2 B                        200001 
     3 C                        200100 
     4 D                        200050 
     5 A                        205000 
     6 B                        260000 
     7 C                        200007 
     8 D                        202000 
     9 R                       2006600
```

9 rows selected

select id,game,point As MinPoint 
from sql_prac where 
point in (select min(point) from sql_prac group by game);

```
    ID DEPT                   MINPOINT
```

---

```
     1 A                          2000 
     2 B                        200001 
     4 D                        200050 
     7 C                        200007 
     9 R                       2006600
```

Comment: You need a correlated sub-query. (And better sample data...)

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to do this, I gave the most simple way according to me,since the data is not a lot so This works fine,And we need not spoon feed everything,for this sample data too the concept can be interpreted with making the answer too complicated by using analytic functions or so.

Comment: It does not work fine... It may look like that since you have no duplicate point values, but if you add some you can end up with wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You should run below simple query :

```
select game, min(point) point from [table_name] group by game
```